# fastest way to check if a key exist in shelve

Tags: python, dictionary, shelve

I have used python shelve library to pre-store a list of key-vector pairs. There are 3 million entries in total, which takes 6 GB memory storage. 
On a separate training file, I need to check for every record if it is a key in the shelve dictionary. This renders my program extremely slow to run. Is there a fast way to check if a key exists in shelve? Or are there other efficient ways to store key-vector pairs in python, so that it is efficient to check if a key exist?

Comment: The best way to do this would be to move to a more efficient k/v store (like redis) or perhaps even a database (depending on what you want to do).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`sqlite3`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html) instead of shelve, and you can query things beyond just asking for arbitrary key. Also do note that `shelve` does not give any promises about such database being usable on any other Python version, or platform or anything thereof.

Even better though, use `sqlite3` *and* store all the keys separately (with unique) and reference these by a foreign key from the vector table; you can scan and keep the key list in memory as a `set` (should need only say ~40 MiB + 3 M * average key size of RAM).

Comment: Is sqlite3 faster when I just need to save one value per key and quickly get it back?